# How can I measure the length of line segments in image mask in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, matlab-figure

I have a binary image ([BW_roi.mat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PeQXhpUco4fA2w3RoI4vOyrJeqzEJNTf/view?usp=sharing)), displayed below. And I wanted to measure the length of every line segment.
[image: image mask]

I tried the solution given in this link [hough-transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/hough-transform.html). But it does not work out for me. It just measured the length of some lines as shown below.

[image: Hough method not working]

I tried the other code

```
clc; clear all; close all;
load BW_ROI.mat

boundaries = bwboundaries(BW_roi_nodot);
patchno=1  %Let select patch 1
b = boundaries{patchno}; % Extract N by 2 matrix of (x,y) locations.
x = b(:, 1);
y = b(:, 2);
```

It though gives me points (x,y) that make up these polygons. But how can I get the line segment length of specific patch?

Comment: Would you also accept a python code?

Comment: My full code of segmentation is written in Matlab. And I am not much familiar with Python. I want to implement it in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose using convexhull in combination with the algorithm [here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41986-ramer-douglas-peucker-algorithm-demo) to reduce the number of vertices in the detected polygons. Seems to work pretty well. I'll leave it to you to use the adjacency matrix produced by `bwboundaries` to throw away duplicates.

```
load BW_ROI.mat

[B,L,N,A] = bwboundaries(BW_roi_nodot);

for k = 1:N
  boundary = fliplr(B{k});
  
  % take a convex hull of the bounded polygon
  idxn = convhull(boundary, 'Simplify', true);
  
  % use this algorithm to further simplify the polygon
  % https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41986-ramer-douglas-peucker-algorithm
  point_reduced = DouglasPeucker(boundary(idxn,:), 5);
  
  % make the shape, get the side lengths
  shp = polyshape(point_reduced);
  vertex_deltas = diff([shp.Vertices; shp.Vertices(1,:)], 1);
  edge_lengths = sqrt(sum(vertex_deltas.^2, 2));
  
  % plot animation
  imshow(BW_roi_nodot), hold on
  plot(shp), drawnow, pause(0.5)
end
```